How to instantiate null object and property in C# with Dapper via SplitOn?
I have this stored procedure in the database:
SELECT 
    Cars.CarId AS carCarId,
    Cars.VinCode AS carVinCode,
    -- Cars.CustomerId AS carCustomerId,
    Cars.NumberPlate AS carNumberPlate,
    Cars.Brand AS carBrand,
    Cars.Model AS carModel,
    Cars.Price AS carPrice,
    Cars.NumberOfSeats AS carNumberOfSeats,
    Cars.NumberOfDoors AS carNumberOfDoors,
    Cars.Mileage AS carMileage,
    Cars.MaxFuelCapacity AS carMaxFuelCapacity,
    Cars.CurrentFuel AS carCurrentFuel,
    Cars.Year AS carYear,
    Cars.IsFitForUse AS carIsFitForUse,
    Cars.Engine AS carEngine,
    Cars.Transmission AS carTransmission,
    Cars.Interior AS carInterior,
    Cars.Wheels AS carWheels,
    Cars.Lights AS carLights,
    Cars.Signal AS carSignal,
    Cars.Color AS carColor,
    -- Cars.DealId AS carDealId,
    -- Cars.StatusId AS carStatusId,
    TransportStatuses.Number AS carStatusId,
    Users.IdNumber AS userIdNumber,
    Users.FirstName AS userFirstName,
    Users.LastName AS userLastName,
    Users.DateOfBirth AS userDateOfBirth,
    Users.UserName AS userUserName,
    Users.Password AS userPassword,
    Users.PassportNumber AS userPassportNumber,
    Users.DrivingLicenseNumber AS userDrivingLicenseNumber,
    -- Users.EmployementDate AS userEmployementDate,
    Users.BasicDiscount AS userBasicDiscount,
    Users.Category AS userCategory,
    Deals.Id AS dealId,
    Deals.CarId AS dealCarId,
    Deals.VinCode AS dealVinCode,
    Deals.CustomerId AS dealCustomerId,
    Deals.Price AS dealPrice,
    Deals.DealType dealDealType,
    Deals.Name AS dealName,
    Inspections.InspectionId AS inspectionInspectionId,
    Inspections.CarId AS inspectionCarId,
    Inspections.VinCode AS inspectionVinCode,
    Inspections.InspectorId AS inspectionInspectorId,
    Inspections.InspectionDate AS inspectionInspectionDate,
    Inspections.StatusId AS inspectionStatusId,
    Repairs.Id AS repairId,
    Repairs.Date AS repairDate,
    Repairs.CarId repairCarId,
    Repairs.VinCode AS repairVinCode,
    Repairs.MechanicId AS repairMechanicId,
    Repairs.IsSuccessfull AS repairIsSuccessfull,
    Repairs.TotalCost AS repairTotalCost,
    Repairs.TechnicalInfo AS repairTechnicalInfo
FROM 
    Cars
LEFT JOIN 
    Users ON Cars.CustomerId = Users.IdNumber
LEFT JOIN  
    Deals ON Deals.CarId = Cars.CarId
LEFT JOIN 
    Inspections ON Inspections.CarId = Cars.CarId
LEFT JOIN 
    Repairs ON Repairs.CarId = Cars.CarId
LEFT JOIN 
    TransportStatuses ON Cars.StatusId = TransportStatuses.Id
WHERE 
    Cars.CarId = @Id;

And the related properties in the class Car:
public Deal? Engagement { get; set; }
public List<Inspection?>? Inspections { get; set; }
public List<Repair?>? Repairs { get; set; }
public Customer? Owner { get; set; }

And this is the mapping code:
SqlConnection connection = SupplementData.DataContext.OpenConnection(connectionString);

string SqlStoredProcedureName = "GetCar";
string carId = id.ToString().ToUpper();

object parameter = new
    {
        Id = carId
    };

List<Car> cars = new List<Car>
    (
        connection.Query<Car, CustomerTemp?, Deal?, Inspection?, Repair?, Car>
        (
           SqlStoredProcedureName,
           (car, customerTemp, deal, inspection, repair) =>
           {
               car.Owner = customerTemp;
               car.Engagement = deal;
               car.Inspections.Add(inspection);
               car.Repairs.Add(repair);

               return car;
           },
           parameter,
           splitOn: "userIdNumber, dealId, inspectionInspectionId, repairId"
        )
);

// LAMBDA-EXPRESSION APPROACH

// IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid, Car>> groupedCars = cars.GroupBy(c => c.CarId);

Car car = cars.First();

car.Inspections = cars.Select(c => c.Inspections.Single()).DistinctBy(i => i.InspectionId).ToList();

car.Repairs = cars.Select(c => c.Repairs.Single()).DistinctBy(r => r.Id).ToList();

SupplementData.DataContext.CloseConnection(connection);

return car;

But any attribute which are not related to Cars table can be NULL! For an example the columns of Repairs can be NULL, all of them. So Dapper in this case is throwing an exception, and I do not know how to fix it... :*(

Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at CarRental.BussinessLayer.Managers.ServiceManager.<>c.b__24_2(Inspection i) in C:\Users\F021\source\repos\Team1_CarRental\CarRental.BussinessLayer\Managers\ServiceManager.cs:line 328
at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctByIterator[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer1 comparer)+MoveNext()   at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at CarRental.BussinessLayer.Managers.ServiceManager.GetCarFromDatabase(Guid id, String connectionString) in C:\Users\F021\source\repos\Team1_CarRental\CarRental.BussinessLayer\Managers\ServiceManager.cs:line 328
at CarRental.Presentation.CarRentalPortal.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\F021\source\repos\Team1_CarRental\CarRental.Presentation\Program.cs:line 95

I am trying to finish my home-task on online course of some private online school, but nobody even trying answers my questions when I ask what to do with it..
If all meaning attributes are not NULL — it works fine. But can exist cars without Customer etc... And when it found such a car — boom, exception.
I have tried to make all properties NULL-able, it helps nothings...

@marc_s
Pardon, I do not understand the edit-things in Stackoverflow yet. You proposing to me to edit the question? Ahh, a different syntax for JOINs T-SQL clauses?

No, I have already edited it, to get rid of a few typos and make it generally more approachable and readable

@marc_s Maybe I will write JOIN-clauses in such manner, it looks not so bad. Thank you. Good that somebody helped.

I have found the problem! This bizarre lambda-expressions make me dizzy... The problem was in lamba-expression exists non-NULL-able temporary return method types.
car.Inspections = cars.Select(c => c.Inspections.Single()).DistinctBy(i => i.InspectionId).ToList();

    car.Repairs = cars.Select(c => c.Repairs.Single()).DistinctBy(r => r.Id).ToList();

I just changed them to...
car.Inspections = cars.Select(c => c.Inspections.Single()).DistinctBy(i => i?.InspectionId).ToList();

    car.Repairs = cars.Select(c => c.Repairs.Single()).DistinctBy(r => r?.Id).ToList();

